# shutil.copy() [Errno 13] Permission Denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

I've been getting an error while trying to use shutil.copy()
What I'm doing is copying a file from one folder to the other, after checking if that file already exists in the destination folder and deleting it:

```
  if os.path.isfile("C:/folder1/file1.csv"):
    full_file_name = os.path.join("C:/folder1/", "file1.csv")
    if os.path.isfile("C:/folder2/file1.csv"):
        os.remove("C:/folder2/file1.csv")
    os.chmod("C:/folder2/",0777)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, "C:/folder2/")
```

The error I've been getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script1.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "shutil.pyc", line 119, in copy
  File "shutil.pyc", line 82, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/folder1/file1.csv'
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: And you have sufficient permissions to open `folder1/file1.csv` for reading? Side note: `os.chmod()` is mostly useless on Windows (it only sets/resets the read-only bit).

Comment: How could I tell? It was created by this python script in the first place. How could I give the script sufficient permissions when creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is:

```
Permission denied: 'C:/folder1/file1.csv'
```

Which means it cannot access `file1.csv`. Check this file is readable by the user running the script.